NATO(Q) keyboard navigation for pages
THIS HAS BEEN SUPERSEDED BY Fix keyboard shortcuts for navigating lists WHICH ADDRESSES THIS AND OTHER KEYBOARD SHORTCUT ISSUES
Description
Inspired from Support paging keyboard shortcuts in NAtOQ 10k-tools. Currently keyboard navigation for changing pages on the "new answers to new questions" tool (NAtOQ/NATOQ/NATO) do not work.
This adds the necessary class in the document so when the keyboard shortcuts are enabled you can use:

P -> N - to go to the next page
P -> P - to go to the previous page

Installation
Direct install (GitHub)
See the code on GitHub
(For instructions how to install userscripts: see the tag wiki here)
Code:
// ==UserScript==
// @name            NATO(Q) keyboard page navigation
// @description     Allow keyboard navigation between different pages (P->N for next / P->P for previous) in the New Answers to Old Questions tool 
// @namespace       https://github.com/PurpleMagick/
// @grant           none
// @inject-into     page
// @match           https://stackoverflow.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions*
// @match           https://serverfault.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions*
// @match           https://superuser.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions*
// @match           https://*.stackexchange.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions*
// @match           https://askubuntu.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions*
// @match           https://stackapps.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions*
// @match           https://mathoverflow.net/tools/new-answers-old-questions*
// @match           https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions*
// @match           https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions*
// @match           https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions*
// @match           https://es.stackoverflow.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions*
// @match           https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions*
// @match           https://meta.serverfault.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions*
// @match           https://meta.superuser.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions*
// @match           https://meta.askubuntu.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions*
// @match           https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tools/new-answers-old-questions*
// @match           https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions*
// @match           https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions*
// @match           https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions*
// @match           https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions*
// @match           https://stackoverflowteams.com/c/tools/new-answers-old-questions*
// @version         1.0
// @author          VLAZ
// ==/UserScript==
(function() {
    const pager = document.querySelector(".pager");
    
    if (!pager) {
        console.warn("Could not find a pager on the NATO page. The fix for keyboard navigation is not active.")
        return;
    }
    
    pager.classList.add("pager-answers");
})();

